# Arithmetic overflow w/ bigints in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm having a problem with arithmetic overflow when converting to bigint in SQL Server 2008.  The following is confusing me.

This works:

```
select 58356453 * 228204732751
```

Answer: 13317218761161292203

But, all other attempts that involve explicit conversion fail.

```
select convert(bigint, 58356453 * 228204732751)
```

result: arithmetic overflow

```
begin 
    declare @key bigint = 58356453,
        @workingVal bigint,
        @primeMultiplier1 bigint = 228204732751;
    set @workingVal = @key * @primeMultiplier1;
end;
```

result: arithmetic overflow

What am I missing here?  I've also tried "cast(BigNumber as bigint)" (don't think it's any different from convert), and various combinations of conversion before/after arithmetic operations.

And, this is on Windows Server 2008 x64

Comment: I tried select convert(bigint, 58356453) * convert(bigint, 228204732751) with the same error

Answer (score 2):

The maxiumum value for a bigint is

[9223372036854775807](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx)

you're returning

13317218761161292203.

I suggest casting to a decimal that has enough precision.

Comment: +1 Brilliant. SELECT (58356453 * 228204732751) - 9223372036854775807 = 4093846724306516396

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [numeric datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258832%28SQL.80%29.aspx).

```
select cast(13317218761161292203 as numeric(38))
```